# Trying to get property 'error' of non-object al lanzar consulta

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

estoy teniendo problemas al hacer una consulta sobre mysql, creo que el problema es de al recuperar una fecha, a ver si me podeís ayudar. Os paso un poco de código.

cde.html

```
<input name="fecha" type="text" class="col-md-2 form-control" id="datepicker" required onchange="load(1);">

<script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
                dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
                todayBtn: "linked",
                language: "es",
                autoclose: true
            });
        });
</script>
```

cde.js
Recojo el valor introducido en el datapicker y lo paso.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    load(1);
});

function load(page){
    var q=$("#q").val();
    var i=$("#i").val();
    var c=$("#c").val();
    var f=$("#datepicker").val();

$("#loader").fadeIn('slow');
$.ajax({
    url:'./ajax/buscar_cde.php?page='+page+'&q='+q+'&i='+i+'&c='+c+'&f='+f,
     beforeSend: function(objeto){
     $('#loader').html('<img src="./img/ajax-loader.gif">');
  },
    success:function(data){
        $("#outer_div").html(data).fadeIn('slow');
        $('#loader').html('');
        $('.archivo').click(function(otro){
            otro.stopPropagation()
            otro.preventDefault();
            var attr=  $(this).prev();
            var archivo = $(this).attr('id');
            nueva=window.open("archivos/visor.php?a="+archivo);return false;
        });
    }
})
```

}

buscar_cde.php
Omito código y paso lo importante.

```
$fecha=limpiar($_REQUEST['f']);
$sql="SELECT count(*) as numrows
            from inventario i
            left join empleados e on e.id_empleado = i.id_empleado
            left join epis ep on ep.id_epi = i.id_epi
            where concat_ws(' ', e.nombre, e.apellidos) like ? and e.id_empleado 

like ? and e.numero_documento like ? i.fecha_entrega like ?";
    $sentencia = $link->prepare($sql) or die($sentencia->error);
            $sentencia->bind_param("ssss", $cadena, $codigo, $identificacion, $fecha);
            $sentencia->execute() or die($sentencia->error);
            $resultado = $sentencia->get_result();
            if($resultado->num_rows >= 1){
                while($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()){
                    $numtotal=$fila["numrows"];
                }
            }
```

Creo que el problema es el formato de la fecha pasado con el datapicker, exactamente  Trying to get property 'error' of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba\ajax\buscar_cde.php on line 71 que es esta

```
$sentencia = $link->prepare($sql) or die($sentencia->error);
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estas tratando de sacar el mensaje de error de la variable que no es (y que de hecho estas inicializando), debería de ser así:

```
$sentencia = $link->prepare($sql) or die($link->error);
```

Ya que es  `$link` (entiendo que es la variable con la conexión) quien tiene ese error.

Comment: Eso era, ¡gracias! :)

Answer (score 0):

Vale, acabo de darme cuenta del error, se me pasó poner un 'and' en la consulta... :S

```
$sql="SELECT count(*) as numrows
        from inventario i
        left join empleados e on e.id_empleado = i.id_empleado
        left join epis ep on ep.id_epi = i.id_epi
        where concat_ws(' ', e.nombre, e.apellidos) like ? and e.id_empleado like ? and e.numero_documento like ? and i.fecha_entrega like ?";
```

Ya funciona correctamenet. ¡Gracias!

Comment: Ese no era tu problema. Me refiero a que ese fallo era la razón de que entrara en el `or die` de la línea 71. Pero el error que has indicado, viene dado por lo que te comento en mi respuesta. En caso de que la consulta falle (ya sea por los parámetros o la conexión) volverá a darte ese fallo en vez de mostrar la razón del error como debería.

Comment: Tienes toda la razón, ahora sí me muestra que el error es en la consulta y no me hace dar vueltas revisando todo el código. ¡Muchas gracias!